# What do I have to do to unjailbreak from Absinthe?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I'm a little new to the whole iPhone / iTunes world, but I'm planning on eventually jailbreaking my iPhone 4S with [Absinthe](http://greenpois0n.com/). The instructions tell me to erase all data from my phone, then restoring from a backup *after* jailbreaking to get my data back.

But what would I have to do in order to actuall remove the jailbreak again?

The Absinthe README doesn't mention this at all, and the website doesn't seem to have that info either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To jailbreak with Absinthe they tell you to erase all data just because the software works faster, but you can do it with all your info. It will only take more time.

I recommend you to use the last version of Absinthe.

To remove jailbreak you have to restore your idevice. (it will restore with the last iOS version at the moment).

Comment: Okay, so "restoring" isn't the same as "restoring from backup"? How do I restore with a fresh iOS?

Comment: When you "restore" a device, you're restoring the software. After a restore is completed and iTunes picks up the device, it'll typically prompt you to begin a restore of the device from any backups you may have available.

Comment: Thanks, @TerranceShaw for the info! — I didn't get your reply though, you need to @-ping any users that aren't the post owners for them to receive a notification :)

Comment: @slhck Ahhhh, good to know! Always something to learn. Thank you for the info!